# Intermediate Value Theorem to show that there is a root $\cos(x) = x^3 - \sqrt{x}, x \in (\pi/4, \pi/2)$

Tags: calculus

$$\cos x=x^3-\sqrt x, x\in(\pi/4,\pi/2)$$
The answer I have currently is $\pi/4$ and only one root in c. Such that $\cos(c) - c^3 + \sqrt{c} = 0$

Can someone help me double check if I'm doing this properly?  Not comfortable with IVT yet.

Comment: There's, at least, another solution. I've checked with secant method numericaly

Comment: @MatMorPau22. Where is the second solution ?

Comment: At $x=1.140865$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider

$$f(x)=x^3-\sqrt{x}-\cos(x)$$

and evaluate $f(\pi/4)$ and $f(\pi/2)$. What can you conclude from the sign changes and the intermediate value theorem?