# Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that there is a root..

Tags: calculus

I am stuck on some math questions that I cannot wrap my head around, so any help will be greatly appreciated. I missed the lecture where the professor taught these due to being sick, so I don't know how to do this.

> Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that there is a root of the given equation in the specified interval.
>
> (a)  $$\ln(x)=e^{-x}, \quad x\in (1,e)$$
>
> (b)  $$\cos(x)=x^3-{\sqrt x}, \quad x\in\left(\frac \pi 4,\frac \pi 2\right)$$

and the other one is:

> Prove that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} {\sqrt x} \left(1+\sin^2 \left(\frac{2\pi}x\right)\right) = 0$$

Comment: Someone asked the exact same question (a) a few hours ago, you might even be able to ask them for their lecture notes if you're on the same course

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460911/use-intermediate-value-theorem-to-show-that-there-is-a-root-of-the-given-equatio

Comment: Your part (b) does not exhibit any equation. It just says $x^3 - \sqrt x$ rather than $x^3-\sqrt x = \cdots\cdots$ or the like. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's probably implied that OP wants a root of $f(x)=x^3-\sqrt{x}$, which is indeed in $[\pi/4,\pi/2]$

Comment: @raspopsicle What have you tried? Do you know how to use the IVT? Have you had a look at what happens when you sub. in the boundary points of the intervals (i.e. $1$ and $e$, etc.) into the equations?

Comment: And as general non-math advice: did you try reading the textbook and going to the professor's office hours?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460871/intermediate-value-theorem-to-show-that-there-is-a-root-cosx-x3-sqrtx and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460911/use-intermediate-value-theorem-to-show-that-there-is-a-root-of-the-given-equatio -- are you in the same class?

Comment: Write down the definition of the intermediate value theorem, and see where that leads you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For parts (a) and (b), use **Marty Cohen**'s hint. For the limit, you can use the substitution $x\mapsto \frac{1}{n}$, to get $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}\left(1+\sin^2(2\pi n)\right)$. Is $\sin^2(\cdot)$ bounded? If so, can we use the bounds of $\sin^2(\cdot)$ to bound your limit? We might also consider $\frac{1}{n}$ as $n\to+\infty$. The figure below shows one way we can bound your limit.

[image: bounds on limit]

For general academic advice, **zipirovich**'s guidance to ask the teacher and read the textbook is invaluable. The teacher's there for a reason - because they know things and can teach them to you. It'd be a waste if you didn't use their resources.

Answer (score 1):

For all these,
rewrite them in the form
$f(x) = 0$.

Find two values
$a$ and $b$ such that
the signs of
$f(a)$ and $f(b)$
are different.

If $f$ is continuous,
then,
by the IVT,
there is at least one root
of $f$
between $a$ and $b$.